# Dynamically Register Commands in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am able to register Events programmatically `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event` and it's listener method. I would like to register command dynamically a similar way. Is there a way to do it in Laravel? Or what is the best way of doing in Laravel except for registering it inside `app/Console/Kernel.php` ?

**Update**
I am able to register a single class via the following code.

```php
use Illuminate\Console\Application as Artisan;

if (app()->runningInConsole()) {
    Artisan::starting(function ($artisan) use ($commandClass) {
        $artisan->resolveCommands($commandClass);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While method provided by Pablo could be a better option for a single directory but if you have commands spread across different namespaces and directories one may end up adding multiple entries in app/Console/Kernel.php

In my use case the `$commandClass` is pulled from multiple xml files spread across multiple composer packages, therefore, I had to use this approach:

```php
use Illuminate\Console\Application as Artisan;

// fetch command classes from different sources and  register it here.
if (app()->runningInConsole()) {
    Artisan::starting(function ($artisan) use ($commandClass) {
        $artisan->resolveCommands($commandClass);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look into your `app/Console/Kernel.php` you should see a statement like this:

```
$this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');
```

This means that all command classes saved in `app/Console/Commands/` will be automatically loaded and registered. Furthermore, if you create a command using artisan, Ex: `php artisan make:command MyCommand`, the class will be stored in `app/Console/Commands/MyCommand.php`.

Comment: Thanks,  I just wanted to register a single class. I think to have found a way and now updating the question with the answer.

Comment: You could override the `load()` method and only register commands if they implement a specific interface for example. But common practice is what Pablo suggested.